# remove border-top gap when set border-right

Tags: css

here is a example:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid black">
    <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline">div1</div>
    <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline">div1</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to create a bar between two child div tag so i use css like above. But it create a gap between child and parent. how can i remove it ?

Comment: it's seeing no gap between them.. check fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/nmfwgouv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add padding to bottom and top on your inline div´s

**HTML**

```
<div style="border: 2px solid black">
  <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline; padding: 2px 0px;">div1</div>
  <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline;  padding: 2px 0px;">div1</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/hra17z5t/16/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `display:inline` and add `display:inline-block`. it will solve your issue.

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid black">
    <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline-block">div1</div>
    <div style="border-right: 3px solid black; display: inline-block">div1</div>
</div>
```